# IF function to calculate duration (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, timeval

I use Importxml to extract the clock from a website that tells the date and time that the market will close ... Well, using the Now () function, I calculate the imported clock minus the current time. I converted the cell with the result of the calculation to the duration format (This way I see how much time is left for the market to close).

```
=importxml("https://cartolafcmix.com/","//div[@class='content']/span/@data-timer")
```

---

```
=NOW()
```

---

```
=A1-A2 (Duration Formatted Cell)
```

I am trying to use the IF function so that if it is more than 22:00:00 and less than 23:00:00, the cell gets written (Alert 22 hours)

```
=IF(AND($A$3>"22:00:00",$A$3<"23:00:00"),"Alert 22 Hours","Error")
```

At the moment are missing 22:18:25 for the market to close, but the result of the formula is giving "error", I do not know what I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(TEXT(A3, "hh")="22", "Alert 22 Hours", A3)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=IF((TIMEVALUE(A3)>TIMEVALUE("22:00:00"))*
    (TIMEVALUE(A3)<TIMEVALUE("23:00:00")), "Alert 22 Hours", A3)
```

[image: 0]

---

one-cell solution:

```
=IF(TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://cartolafcmix.com/", 
 "//div[@class='content']/span/@data-timer")-NOW(), "[hh]")="22", "Alert 22 hours", 
    TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://cartolafcmix.com/", 
 "//div[@class='content']/span/@data-timer")-NOW(), "[hh]:mm:ss"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and for editing my question, but the error still persists mate... Try putting between 16 Hours and 20 Hours for example, it will not appear as true. It keeps returning as an error. @player0

Comment: Mate... =IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A3)>TIMEVALUE("22:00:00"),TIMEVALUE(A3)<TIMEVALUE("23:00:00")), "Alert 22 Hours", A3) ---→ Using your first tip, I added the AND function and it worked perfectly ... That way there will be no alert if you are missing 1 Day and 22 Hours for example ... Only when you are missing 22 hours. Thanks again for your help! It solved perfectly. @player0

Comment: @FredericoMattos fixed: `=IF((TIMEVALUE(A3)>TIMEVALUE("22:00:00"))*
    (TIMEVALUE(A3)<TIMEVALUE("23:00:00")), "Alert 22 Hours", A3)`

Comment: @FredericoMattos added one-cell solution

Comment: AMAZING! @player0